# setFrame not working with a subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, subview

I am implementing a sliding drawer on iOS5 (iPad). I have created the drawer by subclassing UIView. The drawer is added to the main view, which works fine. However, when I try to slide the drawer on/off screen using a swipe gesture and setFrame, the drawer does not move.

I believe I have implemented the gesture recognizer correctly, and the frame is also being set correctly. However, the drawer just does not move. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Below is my code:

The following method is called from viewDidLoad from my controller:

```
- (void)loadVerticalDrawer
{
    NSLog(@"LoadVerticalDrawer Executed");
    verticalDrawerHidden = YES;
    if (verticalDrawerHidden) {
    verticalDrawer = [[VerticalDrawer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(514, 250, 60, 248)];//adjust verticalDrawer height and width here;
    } else {
    verticalDrawer = [[VerticalDrawer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(464, 250, 60, 248)];//adjust verticalDrawer height and width here;    
    }

    verticalDrawer.appsManager = appsManager;
    verticalDrawer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:verticalDrawer];
}
```

The following is also called from viewDidLoad:

```
rightDrawerLeftSwipe = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightDrawerHandleSwipeLeft:)] autorelease];
    rightDrawerLeftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    rightDrawerLeftSwipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    rightDrawerLeftSwipe.delegate = self;
    [verticalDrawer addGestureRecognizer:rightDrawerLeftSwipe];

    rightDrawerRightSwipe = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightDrawerHandleSwipeRight:)] autorelease];
    rightDrawerRightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    rightDrawerRightSwipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    rightDrawerRightSwipe.delegate = self;
    [verticalDrawer addGestureRecognizer:rightDrawerRightSwipe];
```

FInally, this is the handler for the Right Swipe:

```
-(void) rightDrawerHandleSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        if (!verticalDrawerHidden){
        verticalDrawerHidden = YES;
        float x = verticalDrawer.frame.origin.x;
        float y = verticalDrawer.frame.origin.y;
        float width = verticalDrawer.frame.size.width;
        float height = verticalDrawer.frame.size.height;

        NSLog(@"Swipe left, Vertical drawer, x=%f, y=%f, width=%f, height=%f:", x,y,width,height);
        x+=50;
        [verticalDrawer setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
        NSLog(@"Swipe left, Vertical drawer, x=%f, y=%f, width=%f, height=%f:", x,y,width,height);
        return;
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that the frame of verticalDrawer is being set correctly (and the swipe handler is being called as desired), as per the logs, its just that the view is not moving at all!!

Comment: Did you try [verticalDrawer setNeedsDisplay] at the end of gesture handler?

Comment: Nagan, thanks, I did try it at the end of the gesture handler (i.e. after setFrame), but it does nothing.

Comment: ok, so I changed loadVerticalDrawer so that the view is first initialized with cgrectzero, and then I set the frame. I left the rest of the code the same. Now the swipes make the drawer slide in and out!

Comment: However, I have a new problem, that out of the 5 odd buttons that were on verticalDrawer, only one appears. the rest are never added to the view! Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I now changed the view initialization back to the way it originally was, and then called setframe again, and that seems to have fixed both the problems. bizarre, but it works.

Comment: Ya this is very strange. Anyway glad to know you found a solution.